# How to pass another entity info into form in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

What is best practice to include another info in form from another entity?

I have **Student Entity**, **Group Entity**, **StudentsGroup** and **Attendance** Entity.

- **Student** have `id`, `code`, and `name`.
- **Group** have `id` and `name`.
- **StudentsGroup** have `id`, `group_id`, and `student_id`.
- **Attendance** have `id`, `students_group_id`, `date` and `status`.

**Group** can have many **Student** which saved in **StudentsGroup**. Why I make **StudentsGroup**? Because actually 1 **Group** can have some ***sub groups*** like ***SubjectsGroup*** etc. And **Attendance** save student information by **StudentsGroup** ***Id*** which same student can have different `students_group_id`.

[image: Relationship Table]

Now, the problem is : **How to show Student information in collection form of attendance?**
All Entity relationship is declared as object, so actually we can access em freely from any entity. But I don't know how to do that in form. Here my form :

```
<?php
/* Collection Form */
$tanggal = new \DateTime($request->request->get('sifo_adminbundle_studentsgrouping')['tanggal']);
$attendances = new StudentsGrouping();
foreach ($entities as $temp) {
    $entity = new Attendance();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('SifoAdminBundle:Attendance')->findOneBy(array('studentsGrouping' => $temp, 'date' => $tanggal));
    if ($entity){
        $attendances->getAttendances()->add($entity);
    }
}

$form = $this->createCollectionForm($attendances, $id, $tanggal);

return $this->render('SifoAdminBundle:DftAbsensi:manage.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
));
```

This is how I render it in twig :

```
{{ form_start(form_collection) }}
{{ form_row(form_collection.tanggal) }}
    {% for attendance in form_collection.attendances %}
        {{ form_row(attendance.status) }}
    {% endfor %}
{{ form_end(form_collection) }}
```

### ## Concept ##

I'm thinking about creating entity and pass it into form like this :

```
foreach ($entities as $temp) {
    $entity = new Student();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('SifoAdminBundle:Student')->find($temp->getId());
    if ($entity){
        $entities[i] = $entity;
    }
    $i++
}
```

and then in twig show it like this :

```
{{ form_start(form_collection) }}
{{ form_row(form_collection.tanggal) }}
    {% for key, attendance in form_collection.attendances %}
        {{ entities[key].code }}
        {{ entities[key].name }}
        {{ form_row(attendance.status) }}
    {% endfor %}
{{ form_end(form_collection) }}
```

But I feel not comfort with this. Am I really need to make new entity just for showing name and code from Student Entity? Is there a best practice to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use entity field.

```
$builder->add('users', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:User',
    'multiple' => true, /* you can choose more than one */
    'mapped' => false, /* if you are using the form with an entity */
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        /* use query builder to get correct results */
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
    },
));
```

There are two important keys in above.

**`'multiple' => true`** ----- you can able to choose more than one

**`'mapped' => false`** ----- if you are using form with an entity, your form will automatically looks for a connection between these entities and if can not found, throws exception. to avoid of that problem you should set this option to `false`

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Comment: @R I've try this and to get the value, I'm using this in Twig `{{ form.FIELD.vars.VALUE }}` ... I'm still looking for better answer for next 2 Days, if no more answers I'll mark your answer as **Answer**. Thank you for reply.